# How to redirect calls for localhost in a docker container to host.docker.internal

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile, localhost

I have a docker compose set up, where we have an `nginx` server exposing port 80 to the host, an `app` and a `screenshot` service.

The app can pass local urls, html strings or html files to the screenshot service, which in turn screenshots them.

However, in the development environment, if we access the main app under `localhost`, it passes urls to the screenshot service as `http://localhost/somepath`, or even creates HTML string with img src like `http://localhost/img.png`.

This clearly fails to load as the screenshot service is trying to load them off the *screenshot* localhost, not the main app exposed to the host.

What are the options to get round this in development?  So far I have done

1. **Define a custom DNS on the host for `localhost` in the host `/etc/hosts`**

   `127.0.0.1  myapp.internal`

And then add an entries to the `docker-compose.yaml` to define this as pointing to the `docker-host`:

```
    extra_hosts:
       - myapp.internal:host-gateway
```

Pros:

- Works if you use the DNS

Cons:

- you have to make the hosts file change on each dev environment.
- Access the app via `http://localhost` it will still fail.

---

2. **String replace any requests for 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' with `host.docker.internal`**

In the screenshot container we could replace all mentions of localhost in URLS and HTML content with `host.docker.internal` or the name of the nginx container.

Pros:

- Works for everyone out the box

Cons:

- It will replace every mention of the word `localhost` unless we do some complex regex to ONLY replace src/href etc etc.
- modifying the html could introduce errors

---

3. **Run the whole thing as a `host` network ?**

Pros:

- should work, as `localhost` is always the host.
- Would work out the box for new dev environments

Cons:

- Feels like overkill, and feels wrong exposing *all* the containers on the host  - but its only for development

Also, I couldn't get this to work.  I added `network_mode: host` to all the services but nothing was running under localhost.

---

Am I missing anything here?  Is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Currently I'm thinking option 1, and we throw an error in development if it detects any localhost URLS passed to the screenshot service.

Comment: That sounds like "running locally" vs. "deployed in containers" are two separate environments and have two different host name sets, which is normal.  Can you make it configurable where the screen-shot service is running?  If it was something you could set with an environment variable, you could have a default in code set for a local-developer use case but change its value in a Compose `environment:` block.

Comment: Yes - and that is how it is set up, the dev compose file sets a ENV var telling the other services how to access the screenshot service.  This issue is the other way round though - when a url like "http://localhost/myPage" is given to the screenshot service, the screenshot service will resolve that to its OWN localhost - not the host machine.

Comment: oh - and some are macs, so don't thing host network works anyway!